# diagonal map and differentials

Tags: algebraic-geometry

when we want to define differentials $\Omega_{A/B}$ we use the product map $g:A\otimes A \longrightarrow A$ and we consider its kernel $I$ and define differentials as $I/I^2$. If we go to geometry we have a map $f:\operatorname{spec}(A)$$\longrightarrow \operatorname{spec}(A\otimes A)$. The kernel $I$ here corresponds to $V(I)$ from  which we can see that $V(I)=\{(p,q):I\subseteq\sum a_i \otimes 1+1 \otimes b_i :a_i\in p , b_i \in q \}$. now I have the following questions:

1. Am I right about $V(I)$?
2. We know that $g$ is surjective so we must have $V(I)$ isomorphic to $\operatorname{spec}(A)$ via the map $f$.I think it means that $V(I)$ is isomorphic to $\{(p,p):p \in \operatorname{spec(A)}\}$ because $f$ is diagonal map. Am I right?if yes how can we give explicit map between $V(I)$ and this set.I mean how can we give this isomorphism?

Comment: On typesetting, `\Omega_{A/B}` gives $\Omega_{A/B}$, `\{ \}` gives $\{ \}$, and  `\operatorname{spec}(A)` gives $\operatorname{spec}(A)$. Also, it would be more readable if you typeset entire formulas in a single pair of `$ ... $`, rather than putting dollar signs around individual symbols.